# Register mouseover of an element beneath another one

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to register a mouseover event on an element that is beneath another element. I have rows which, when moused over, make a new div appear and positions it on top of the hovered div.

Here's the page: http://www.brunobryan.com/dev/stephanebourgeois/index/

When you mouseover a row, an image appears on the right. I would like to register the mouseover event on the row even when the mouse hovers above the image.

Comment: Why not just wrap the image tag in a link the same as the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can permit the cursor to pass-through the image using [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events):

```
#index-hover {
    pointer-events: none
}
```

Note, this [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) in all browsers. Better support if you use SVG.

Comment: from MDN: Note that preventing an element from being the target of mouse events by using pointer-events does not necessarily mean that mouse event listeners on that element cannot or will not be triggered.

Comment: @nathangonzalez Correct, however if all he wants to do is permit mouse-events on the `tr` is that obstructed by the `img`, pointer-events is sufficient.

Comment: agreed, just wanted to make sure that fact was noted, not that your answer is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible, you have a couple of options for workarounds.

Either a) Register the hover event on a container that will contain both the row and the image.

or

b) Bind the same hover event on the image aswell.

Comment: I was skeptical it could be done, but couldn't find a confirmation anywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer here is going to be that your `<img>` tag needs to be placed inside of the `<tr>` tag, and then absolutely positioned.  you'll probably want to make the row relatively positioned so that you can use the row's position as context.

Comment: Indeed, that would be the best workaround. It was faster to set it up this way though, and I was curious as to if it could be done.